# Difference between || and ||=?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby.

What is the difference between `||` and `||=`?

```
>> a = 6 || 4
=> 6
>> a ||= 6
=> 6
```

Sounds like they are the same.

Comment: not from Ruby, but `||=` may be similar as `+= `

Comment: `||=` is very different from `+=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`||=` will set the left-hand value to the right hand value only if the left-hand value is falsey.

In this case, both 6 and 4 are truthy, so `a = 6 || 4` will set `a` to the first truthy value, which is `6`.

`a ||= 6` will set `a` to 6 only if `a` is falsey. That is, if it's nil or false.

```
a = nil
a ||= 6
a ||= 4
a # => 6
```

Comment: sounds like undefined also include. based on the above answer?

Comment: Yes, you can use `||=` to define variables that were previously undefined.

Comment: @KitHo yes I did include that.. :)

Answer (score 4):

> `x ||= y` means assigning `y` to `x` if x is *null or undefined or false* ; it is a shortcut to `x = y unless x`.
>
> With Ruby short-circuit operator `||` the right operand is not evaluated if the left operand is truthy.

Now some quick examples on my above lines on `||=` :

*when x is undefined and n is `nil`:*

> with `unless`

```
y = 2
x = y unless x
x # => 2

n = nil
m = 2
n = m unless n
m # => 2
```

> with `=||`

```
y = 2
x ||= y
x # => 2

n = nil
m = 2
n ||= m
m # => 2
```

Answer (score 3):

a ||= 6  only assigns 6 if it wasn't already assigned. ( actually, falsey, as Chris said)

```
a = 4
a ||= 6
=> 4

a = 4 || 6
=> 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can expand `a ||= 6` as

```
a || a = 6
```

So you can see that it use `a` if `a` is not `nil` or `false`, otherwise it will assign value to `a` and return that value. This is commonly used for memoization of values.

**Update**

Thanks to the first comment for pointing out the true expansion of the `||=` (or equal) operator. I learned something new and found this interesting post that talks about it. http://dablog.rubypal.com/2008/3/25/a-short-circuit-edge-case

Comment: This is wrong. It (admittedly unintuitively) expands to `a || a = 6`

Comment: I must admit I never thought of that expansion. @EdS. Do you have a source or a way I can check that? I updated my answer with it because it does make sense.

Comment: Check one of the two duplicate topics.  I have to admit, I thought the same as you a couple of years ago and answered the same question, but I was corrected by a more knowledgeable SO member.  EDIT: Oops, I see you found it.

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions `a = 6 || 4` and `a ||= 6` return the same result but the difference is that `||=` assigns value to variable if this variable is nil or false.