# understanding line of ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am studying the source code for fat free CRM.  I am trying to understand what this specific line of code in one of the app helpers does:

```
options[:selected] = (@account && @account.id) || 0
```

It seems to be setting the value of the options hash with key `:selected` to the value of the instance variable `@account` or `0` (if `@account` doesn't exist).

What is the `&& @account.id` doing?

Comment: see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461737/difference-between-and/17461794#17461794

Comment: see here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby

Comment: do some research before asking any questions in SO...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's making sure `@account` isn't falsey, and if it isn't, it sets the option to the account's `id`. Written long-hand it would be equivalent to this:

```
options[:selected] = if @account && @account.id
                       @account.id
                     else
                       0
                     end
```

Or

```
options[:selected] = (@account && @account.id) ? @account.id : 0
```

I'd probably use [the `andand` gem](https://github.com/raganwald/andand/) which makes it look like this:

```
options[:selected] = @account.andand.id || 0
```

Comment: `andand` is actually a [gem](https://github.com/raganwald/andand/) though, right? From what I can tell, it's not built into Ruby.

Comment: @JamesChevalier Correct, it's a gem.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to writing,

```
options[:selected] = (@account != nil ? (@account.id != nil ? @account.id : 0) : 0)
```

however, Ruby programmers prefer the way you have indicated in your question as you can see that above code can get really unreadable.  Also, Ruby (and other dynamic programming languages such as JavaScript) have concept of truthy and falsy values which allows one to write concise and more readable code.  You can read about that here in this article: [A question of truth](http://blog.leshill.org/blog/2012/03/25/a-question-of-truth.html).

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks Dave, I amended my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a very common problem to ensure that an object is not nil, there is a method for that in rails (but not in ruby directly):

```
options[:selected] = @account.try(:id) || 0
```

`try(:id)` will return `nil` if `@account` is `nil` or `false` and will call `:id` on `@account` in any other case. That means also that it will raise an error, if the object is not nil or false and does not respond to id.

Answer (score 0):

```
options[:selected] = (@account && @account.id) || 0
```

This line of code will not set `options[:selected]` to be `@account` or 0, but rather `@account.id` or 0. The reason being that `(@account && @account.id)` will return the last statement evaluated, which would be `@account.id` if both are true.

As others have said, `(@account && @account.id)` is going to first verify that `@account` actually exists; if it does, thanks to short-circuiting, it will then check if `@account.id` exists and will set `options[:selected]` to it if it does. If, however, `@account` does not exist, then the value will be set to 0.